# Putting an outline around multiple inline elements across line break?

Tags: html, css, layout, inline

I want to put a colorful outline around a bunch of inline elements. Is there any easy way to make this look right within the flow of the text?

Here's the HTML:

```
<span>Text Before</span>
<div class="border">
    <div>This</div>
    <div>is</div>
    <div>not</div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>public</div>
    <div>service</div>
    <div>announcement.</div>
</div>
<span>Text After</span>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.border {
    display: inline;
    background-color: pink;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    border: solid;
}
.border > div {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```

Screenshot with `.border` `display: inline`:

[image]

Screenshot with `.border` `display: inline-block`:

[image]

I want it to look roughly like this (accomplished with a mixture of manual line height, padding, and relative positioning... ugh!):

[image]

Basically, `inline-block` elements do everything right, but they don't break apart between lines as would `inline` elements. But `inline` elements collapse their height and have to be manually adjusted. Is there really no way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line-height on container div.

```
.border {
    display: inline;
    background-color: pink;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
    border: solid;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.border > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```

Comment: Right, manual line height (plus some other things) is how arrived at the last image in my post. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do that without manual adjustment, though.

Comment: How about, making inner-divs inline-block and adding a margin-bottom.

Comment: Having the inner divs be `inline-block` does not actually affect the way their parent div is sized. (In other words, it remains at height zero.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a cop-out answer on my part, but It Works™, at least for my purposes, so I'm using it until something better comes up.

If you're willing to commit the relatively minor crime of putting a `span` around the content of each inner `div` and setting the text style for the `span` instead of the `div`, you can make each of the `div`s an `inline-block`, give the background and border style to each individual `div` instead of the parent `div`, set the left/right `margin` of each `div`, to 0, and extend the borders of the `div`s via `padding` to make it *seem* like one continuous background rect. If you want an outline, you can use the `nth-item` selectors and set the borders accordingly.

Here's the revised HTML (also compressed onto one line, to get rid of the spaces between `inline-block` elements):

```
<span>Text Before</span>
<div class="border">
    <div><span>This</span></div><div><span>is</span></div><div><span>not</span></div><div><span>a</span></div><div><span>public</span></div><div><span>service</span></div><div><span>announcement.</span></div>
</div>
<span>Text After</span>
```

And here's the revised CSS:

```
.border {
    display: inline;
    word-spacing: 0;
}
.border > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
.border > div:nth-child(1) {
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.border > div:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
}
.border > div > span {
    background-color: lavender;
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

This technique breaks down if you want something more complex than a background color with a border, but for my purposes, the benefits — those being far simpler CSS and mostly automatic layout — outweigh the cons.